# Cauchy's Theorem (difficult problem)

Tags: complex-analysis

> Given the contour integral
>
> $$ \frac{1}{2 \pi i}  \int_{\gamma}   \frac{(1+zx)^{k+1/3}}{(z-a)^2z}  d z$$
>
> where $|x| < \frac1a$ and $\gamma$ is a closed positively oriented countour enclosing both $0$ and $a.$

I apply Cauchy's Theorem to conclude that

$$p(x)+(1+ax)^{1/3}q(x).$$

However I'm having difficulty finding $p(x)$ and $q(x)$.

I know that

$$(1+xz)^{k + 1/3} = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \binom{k+1/3}{n}(xz)^n$$ which could be useful.